# Getter inside an interface and inside an abstract class

Tags: java

I have this interface in which i am supposed to declare some getters, and implement those in an abstract class. And this is what I have so far:

```
abstract class AbstractArticle implements Article {
    final private String name;
    final private double price;
    final private String description;

    AbstractArticle(String name,double price,String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Now the idea is that inside this AbstractArticle class I will call the getName() method an just return name; Am I doing this the right way or not? Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, getters just return properties, and sometimes log stuff (although you don't need that). However, getters are usually implemented in non-abstract classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it correctly but note that you will not be able to create instance of this abstract class. You will need to implement another class that inherits from the abstract class you defined to use those function. The advantage of abstract classes is that you will be able to create several classes that uses those implementations.

The instance using your implementation will be declared as follow :

```
class MyCustomArticle extends AbstractArticle {
    // Some other functions and variables
}
```

Comment: Oh,yea I am aware of that, actually that is the part I am working on right now, creating two more classes that will inherit the abstract class. Thank you for you answer!